# Flash Player - Fullscreen without user interaction (automated testing)

Tags: flash, testing, selenium, fullscreen

At the moment I'm using Selenium-Flex to write functional tests for a video playback app.

At the moment, I need to test that the app behaves appropriately when switched to fullscreen mode - make sure that the control bar is in a reasonable spot, the video resizes appropriately, etc., and of course to do that I need an automated way to make Flash Player go fullscreen.

For good reason, Flash's security features prevent being able to fullscreen except in response to user input. *Actual* user input, a javascript callback being called does not count.

Is there any way to disable this security feature on my test rig, so I can actually run my automated tests on fullscreen mode? Barring that, is there any way to put Flash into fullscreen mode externally, so I can hack it up to work that way?

Comment: might be a bit of a stretch, but maybe you could start a Sikuli script just for pressing the fullscreen button ? http://sikuli.csail.mit.edu/

Answer (score 0):

use autoit to write the script and then use MouseClick method in your script to press the specific button:

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm